# Extra characters when pasting into zsh w/ zprezto

Tags: zsh

- OS: Arch Linux
- Desktop Environment: GNOME3
- Shell: zsh (w/ zprezto)

When I paste text, for example `https://superuser.com/questions/ask` into my terminal I get the following text:

`^[[200~https://superuser.com/questions/ask~`

These extra characters only appear when zprezto is loaded. I'm guessing there is a setting in zprezto that does this, but I can't figure out which one so that I can turn it off.

Does anyone know?

.zprofile:

```
#
# Executes commands at login pre-zshrc.
#
# Authors:
#   Sorin Ionescu <sorin.ionescu@gmail.com>
#

#
# Browser
#

if [[ "$OSTYPE" == darwin* ]]; then
  export BROWSER='open'
fi

#
# Editors
#

export EDITOR='nano'
export VISUAL='nano'
export PAGER='less'

#
# Language
#

if [[ -z "$LANG" ]]; then
  export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
fi

#
# Paths
#

# Ensure path arrays do not contain duplicates.
typeset -gU cdpath fpath mailpath path

# Set the the list of directories that cd searches.
# cdpath=(
#   $cdpath
# )

# Set the list of directories that Zsh searches for programs.
path=(
  /usr/local/{bin,sbin}
  $path
)

#
# Less
#

# Set the default Less options.
# Mouse-wheel scrolling has been disabled by -X (disable screen clearing).
# Remove -X and -F (exit if the content fits on one screen) to enable it.
export LESS='-F -g -i -M -R -S -w -X -z-4'

# Set the Less input preprocessor.
# Try both `lesspipe` and `lesspipe.sh` as either might exist on a system.
if (( $#commands[(i)lesspipe(|.sh)] )); then
  export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/env $commands[(i)lesspipe(|.sh)] %s 2>&-"
fi
```

.zshrc

```
#
# Executes commands at the start of an interactive session.
#
# Authors:
#   Sorin Ionescu <sorin.ionescu@gmail.com>
#

# Source Prezto.
if [[ -s "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto/init.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto/init.zsh"
fi

# Customize to your needs...
```

.zpreztorc

```
#
# Sets Prezto options.
#
# Authors:
#   Sorin Ionescu <sorin.ionescu@gmail.com>
#

#
# General
#

# Set case-sensitivity for completion, history lookup, etc.
# zstyle ':prezto:*:*' case-sensitive 'yes'

# Color output (auto set to 'no' on dumb terminals).
zstyle ':prezto:*:*' color 'yes'

# Set the Zsh modules to load (man zshmodules).
# zstyle ':prezto:load' zmodule 'attr' 'stat'

# Set the Zsh functions to load (man zshcontrib).
# zstyle ':prezto:load' zfunction 'zargs' 'zmv'

# Set the Prezto modules to load (browse modules).
# The order matters.
zstyle ':prezto:load' pmodule \
  'environment' \
  'terminal' \
  'editor' \
  'history' \
  'directory' \
  'spectrum' \
  'utility' \
  'completion' \
  'prompt' \
  'syntax-highlighting' \
  'tmux' \
  'autosuggestions' \

#
# Autosuggestions
#

# Set the query found color.
zstyle ':prezto:module:autosuggestions' color 'yes'
# zstyle ':prezto:module:autosuggestions:color' found ''

#
# Completions
#

# Set the entries to ignore in static */etc/hosts* for host completion.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:completion:*:hosts' etc-host-ignores \
#   '0.0.0.0' '127.0.0.1'

#
# Editor
#

# Set the key mapping style to 'emacs' or 'vi'.
zstyle ':prezto:module:editor' key-bindings 'emacs'

# Auto convert .... to ../..
# zstyle ':prezto:module:editor' dot-expansion 'yes'

# Allow the zsh prompt context to be shown.
#zstyle ':prezto:module:editor' ps-context 'yes'

#
# Git
#

# Ignore submodules when they are 'dirty', 'untracked', 'all', or 'none'.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:git:status:ignore' submodules 'all'

#
# GNU Utility
#

# Set the command prefix on non-GNU systems.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:gnu-utility' prefix 'g'

#
# History Substring Search
#

# Set the query found color.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:history-substring-search:color' found ''

# Set the query not found color.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:history-substring-search:color' not-found ''

# Set the search globbing flags.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:history-substring-search' globbing-flags ''

#
# OS X
#

# Set the keyword used by `mand` to open man pages in Dash.app
# zstyle ':prezto:module:osx:man' dash-keyword 'manpages'

#
# Pacman
#

# Set the Pacman frontend.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:pacman' frontend 'yaourt'

#
# Prompt
#

# Set the prompt theme to load.
# Setting it to 'random' loads a random theme.
# Auto set to 'off' on dumb terminals.
zstyle ':prezto:module:prompt' theme 'pure'

# Set the working directory prompt display length.
# By default, it is set to 'short'. Set it to 'long' (without '~' expansion)
# for longer or 'full' (with '~' expansion) for even longer prompt display.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:prompt' pwd-length 'short'

#
# Ruby
#

# Auto switch the Ruby version on directory change.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:ruby:chruby' auto-switch 'yes'

#
# Python
#

# Auto switch the Python virtualenv on directory change.
zstyle ':prezto:module:python:virtualenv' auto-switch 'yes'

# Automatically initialize virtualenvwrapper if pre-requisites are met.
 zstyle ':prezto:module:python:virtualenv' initialize 'yes'

#
# Screen
#

# Auto start a session when Zsh is launched in a local terminal.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:screen:auto-start' local 'yes'

# Auto start a session when Zsh is launched in a SSH connection.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:screen:auto-start' remote 'yes'

#
# SSH
#

# Set the SSH identities to load into the agent.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:ssh:load' identities 'id_rsa' 'id_rsa2' 'id_github'

#
# Syntax Highlighting
#

# Set syntax highlighters.
# By default, only the main highlighter is enabled.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:syntax-highlighting' highlighters \
#   'main' \
#   'brackets' \
#   'pattern' \
#   'line' \
#   'cursor' \
#   'root'
#
# Set syntax highlighting styles.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:syntax-highlighting' styles \
#   'builtin' 'bg=blue' \
#   'command' 'bg=blue' \
#   'function' 'bg=blue'
#
# Set syntax pattern styles.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:syntax-highlighting' pattern \
#   'rm*-rf*' 'fg=white,bold,bg=red'

#
# Terminal
#

# Auto set the tab and window titles.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:terminal' auto-title 'yes'

# Set the window title format.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:terminal:window-title' format '%n@%m: %s'

# Set the tab title format.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:terminal:tab-title' format '%m: %s'

# Set the terminal multiplexer title format.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:terminal:multiplexer-title' format '%s'

#
# Tmux
#

# Auto start a session when Zsh is launched in a local terminal.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:tmux:auto-start' local 'yes'

# Auto start a session when Zsh is launched in a SSH connection.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:tmux:auto-start' remote 'yes'

# Integrate with iTerm2.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:tmux:iterm' integrate 'yes'

# Set the default session name:
# zstyle ':prezto:module:tmux:session' name 'YOUR DEFAULT SESSION NAME'

#
# Utility
#

# Enabled safe options. This aliases cp, ln, mv and rm so that they prompt
# before deleting or overwriting files. Set to 'no' to disable this safer
# behavior.
# zstyle ':prezto:module:utility' safe-ops 'yes'
```

Comment: Those sequences look like they come from the terminal bracketed-paste feature. What version of zsh have you got? Recent versions support it natively: `bindkey -L|grep 200` should show the sequence bound to bracketed-paste. Otherwise you may have some safe-paste plugin from prezto.

Answer (score 11):

Problem was Ctrl-V followed by Ctrl-Shift-V

The terminal expects Ctrl-Shift-V for paste. Thanks to muscle memory, my workflow was: Ctrl-V, think 'why didn't this paste? Oh yeah...', then Ctrl-Shift-V. This would add those extra characters. It all happened so fast that I didn't even realize I was doing it every time.

If I just hit Ctrl-Shift-V the first time, then everything works as expected.

Comment: You might run into this in vim too even outside of the terminal. CTRL-V is a shortcut to say the next keystroke (whatever it is) should be recorded as the visual representation of an action instead of taking the action itself.

Comment: Whilst this is true, is there any way to guard against it? I thought the safe-paste plugin may do it but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: the muscle memory being too strong, the solution I found was to assign CTRL+V to the least armful action my terminal offers: now when I CTRL+V, the terminal scrolls one line down, then I can go to the 'why didn't this paste? Oh yeah...' step without having to clean up undesired characters. In my terminal, Terminator, I could assign this shortcut from the preferences menu

Comment: Couldn't ctrl-v be mapped to paste? Controversial I know - just curios what the downside of that would be.